# How to make a package appear into a future stack LTS snapshot again?

Tags: haskell-stack

Sometimes certain packages get outdated, and they are not included subsequent `stack` LTS's snapshots. Is there a standard procedure to have these packages back into a future snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you have to do is to get your package into nightly. For this, you [open a PR on the `fpco/stackage` GitHub project](https://github.com/fpco/stackage). It is recommended to follow the given template and make sure all checkboxes are ticked (that is, you tested that the package works locally with the latest nightly).

Once the PR is opened, the curator on duty from the Stackage curator team will test it and if all is good your package will land into nightly. This process usually takes less than a day after all issues are solved, but sometimes it could take 1 or 2 if there are snags in releasing the nightly for the current day.

Then, before the end of the week (when the Stackage curator team usually releases the new LTS version), you [make a PR on the LTS repo](https://github.com/fpco/lts-haskell), checking again all the checkboxes in the template, just like above. Then, it can take a while until the package lands in LTS, but you have nothing more to do after that.

All this infomration is also presented, in a condensed form, in [the README for maintainers](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/blob/master/MAINTAINERS.md#adding-a-package-to-an-lts-snapshot)

Comment: One piece of information that I don't seem to find, is whether I need to upload the package to hackage before opening the first PR (into the `fpco/stackage`).

Comment: You do, the recommended way is to have the package on Hackage first.