# Is there a tool for upgrading the dependecies' upper bounds to the latest versions of each dependency?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm trying to upgrade the dependencies of the [`pipes-files`](https://github.com/jwiegley/pipes-files) package, so that it can be [included in the latest `stack` LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49090058/2289983). The `pipes-files` package does not contain a `stack.yaml` file, and the `pipes-files.cabal` file contains quite some upper and lower bounds on its dependencies, e.g.:

```
  base                >=4.7  && <4.10
, transformers        >=0.3  && <0.6
, transformers-base   >=0.3  && <0.6
-- and quite some more ...
```

Is there a tool that I can run to get the latest versions of each of these dependencies? The closest thing I could find was [`packdeps`](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/) but it will require me to search for the dependencies one by one.

Comment: There is [`cabal gen-bounds`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-2.0.1.1/doc/users-guide/developing-packages.html#generating-dependency-version-bounds), though I haven't used it, and can't confirm it does what you want right now (I'm having some trouble to use cabal-install through Stack in the provisional, hastily improvised, Windows-based Haskell environment I find myself in right now).

Comment: Great! `cabal get-bounds` seems to be useful here. The way of working I can think of the is: remove all the bounds but `base` and then let `cabal get-bounds` find the bounds. You should write this as an answer ;)

Comment: "You should write this as an answer" -- I would be more comfortable with that if I was sure it worked (or if you'd confirm it does). I suspect there might be some extra steps involved so that cabal-install accounts for the LTS snapshot you are using.

Comment: After thinking a little more about this, I have come up with a plan that might be easier to get to work. It involves [Jenga](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jenga) as an intermediate to retrieve the LTS versions. I'll get back to you in ~12 hours, hopefully with a verified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary notes:

- *hierarchy*, a dependency of *pipes-files*, has the same issue you are trying to work around -- it is not in Stackage and has version bounds outdated with respect to the latest LTS. That means you'll first have to get it to build successfully, and then [add your tweaked version of it to the extra-deps in the `stack.yaml` of *pipes-files*](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps).
- [`cabal gen-bounds`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-2.0.1.1/doc/users-guide/developing-packages.html#generating-dependency-version-bounds), which "suggest[s] dependency version bounds that conform to Package Versioning Policy", is, in principle, the right tool for the job. However, getting cabal-install to behave according to the restrictions of a Stack-centric environment is not always straightforward. While this seems enough to run `cabal gen-bounds` from a bash shell in the absence of a Stack-independent GHC installation...

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:$(stack path --compiler-bin) cabal gen-bounds
  ```

  ... I couldn't figure out how to get it to follow the version restrictions of the Stack(age) snapshot -- in particular, the `--package-db` option, [which can be helpful with commands such as `cabal configure`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haskell-stack/8HJ6DHAinU0/J68U6AXTsasJ), doesn't seem to be accepted by `gen-bounds`.

As I don't know how to make `cabal gen-bounds` and Stack cooperate, I will suggest a somewhat more convoluted method, but one that doesn't require using cabal-install directly. It uses [Jenga](https://github.com/erikd/jenga), a tool that can retrieve the version information left implicit by your choice of Stackage snapshot. Jenga is not on Stackage; to install it with Stack, grab the sources from GitHub (or with `stack unpack jenga`) and then run `stack init --solver` followed by `stack install`.

1. Remove all version bounds from the `hierarchy.cabal` file (or whatever the relevant .cabal file is).
2. `stack init --solver`, to create a `stack.yaml` file with any extra-deps that might be necessary. (You can use `--resolver` to explicitly choose the snapshot to be used.)
3. `stack build`, as a sanity check that the package is buildable.
4. In the generated `stack.yaml`, check whether the `extra-deps` field is commented out; if so, uncomment it. This is necessary for step #6 to work.
5. `jenga -i hierarchy.cabal`, which will print the exact dependency versions Stack would use to build the package.
6. Paste the versions Jenga gave you into the `build-depends` of the .cabal file, adjusting then if desired (at a minimum, you'll probably want to relax the minor version bounds for PVP compliance -- e.g. changing `base == 4.9.1.0` to `base == 4.9.*`).